# Проверка адреса сервера и дальнейший редирект

Tags: веб-программирование, защита, php, html, безопасность

У меня на сайте в текстовом файле будет список тех сайтов, на которых я разрешаю выполнение скрипта.

> Например: yandex.ru, google.com,
> mail.ru, ...

Скрипт должен прочесть этот список, и если в нем нет значения текущего $_SERVER, то выполнится редирект.

Как реализовать проверку разрешенных доменов?

---

.

С этим разобрались.

Теперь другая проблема:

Указанный скрипт учитывает только домены второго уровня.

А как быть с доменными именами, которые располагаются в зонах ".com.ua", ".dp.ua", ".in.ua" и др.?

---

.

Всё, разобрался!

Огромное преогромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама проверка состоит в сравнивании каждого хоста с текущим.

```
/**
 * Преобразование какого-нибудь.длинного.хоста в домен второго уровня (домен.зона)
 */
function trimHost($host)
{
    // разбиваем на массив, разделителем служит точка
    $chunks = explode('.', trim($host));
    // меньше двух составляющих - возвращаем false
    if (sizeof($chunks) < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    // собираем хост из двух последних составляющих
    return implode('.', array_slice($chunks, -2));
}

function verifyHost($currentHost, $hosts)
{
    // берем каждый хост
    foreach ($hosts as $host) {
        // принудительно делаем из него домен второго уровня
        $host = trimHost($host); // получаем домен второго уровня или false
        // проверяем, что не вернулся false и что такой хост присутствует в текущем
        if ($host && strpos($currentHost, $host) !== false) { // проверяем наличие этого домена в текущем хосте.
            // нашел - верни true
            return true;
        }
    }
    // прошел по всем и не нашел - верни false
    return false;
}

// читаем файл hosts.txt в текущей директории и разбиваем его по запятым на массив хостов
$hosts = explode(',', file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/hosts.txt');
// делаем проверку
if (!verifyHost($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $hosts) {
    /// проверка не прошла
}
```

только такая защита ломается на раз-два

Comment: Ага... начинаю по чуть-чуть "въезжать".
Ну, тут используется для сравнения файл hosts.txt, который находится в той же папке. У меня этот файл будет находится на моем сервере.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно вот эту строку:
$hosts = explode(',', file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/hosts.txt');
заменить на вот такую:
$hosts = explode(',', file_get_contents('http://мой_сайт.ру/hosts.txt');
?

И еще, скрипт выдает ошибку:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /index.php on line 22

line 22 - это вышеуказанная строчка с адресом к файлу hosts.txt

Comment: Всё есть, разобрался. Но теперь вопрос в другом:

домены второго уровня не учитываются?

Например, есть сайт google.com.ua

насколько я понимаю, скрипт не обращает внимание на слово google.

Comment: разобрался. спасибо!